# Is there any best way to insert and retrieve data from sp list

Tags: fast-for-sharepoint

```
namespace Gridwebpart.VisualWebPart1
{
    public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web;
                SPList list = site.Lists["GridList"];
                SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;
                DataTable dt = items.GetDataTable();
                Gridnames.DataSource = dt;
                Gridnames.DataBind();

            }

        }

        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPList list = site.Lists["GridList"];
            SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;
            //SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(1);
            SPListItem item = items.Add();
            item["Title"] = txtName.Text;
            item["Description"] = txtDescription.Text;
            item["IS Sharepoint 2010 Developer"] = chkbox.Checked;
            item.Update();
            site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            txtName.Text = "";
            txtDescription.Text = "";
             chkbox.Checked=false;
             items = list.Items;
             DataTable dt = items.GetDataTable();
             Gridnames.DataSource = dt;
             Gridnames.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure whats best but you can use [SPQuery](http://sarangasl.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/sharepoint-list-c-part-1.html) (only for reading) as well to get Data out of sharepoint, however if you want someone to look at your code and improve it then I would suggest you try this question on

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

hope it helped ;)

Just realized your not disposing your SharePoint objects in code, I would recommend you to look at this MSDN article

[Disposing SharePoint Objects](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&checkda=1&ct=1346227308&rver=6.0.5276.0&wp=MCLBI&wlcxt=msdn$msdn$msdn&wreply=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248%2528v=office.12%2529.aspx&lc=1033&id=254354&mkt=en-US)

Comment: added to your answer, you can add an item efficiently by following this blog:

http://blog.robgarrett.com/2009/02/25/efficient-way-to-add-a-new-item-to-a-sharepoint-list/

Comment: There is no SharePoint objects in his code that he's allowed to dispose. Disposing the SPWeb from SPContext.Current.Web would be an error

Comment: your right, I just had a quick look before i left that time